# Multi Row Slides Layout responsive rows

Tags: responsive, swiper.js

I am using swiper through ionic framework so I want to create a slide with 2 rows and 4 columns in desktop.
The slide must be 1 row 1 column on mobile to see the 8 slides individually.
I made that with slick.js https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ and looks great but I can't find the options to achieve this with swiper.
Is it possible?
Thank you!